# Finding hidden files in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to locate *only* the hidden files in a given subtree of the file system. The search box in Windows Explorer has facilities for tags like

```
Date Modified:
```

or

```
Size:
```

Is there a similar tag for hidden? This:

```
Hidden: true
```

doesn't seem to work.

Any other alternatives to find only the hidden files?

Comment: See http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/fede1d8e-130c-4e69-9b2b-48cf3f904c43 for details.

Answer (score 1):

In the Windows Search, you should be able to use `attributes:2`.

The attributes are a bit field with the [following values](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/fede1d8e-130c-4e69-9b2b-48cf3f904c43):

```
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY = 1
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN = 2
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM = 4
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 16
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE = 32
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED = 64
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = 128
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY = 256
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SPARSE_FILE = 512
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT = 1024
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED = 2048
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE = 4096
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED = 8192
```

Just add the ones you're looking for together.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to get this to work on Windows Server 2008 R-2. Perhaps on another version?

Comment: @MgSam: Is the Windows Search Service role service installed on the server? It's part of the File Services role.

Answer (score 0):

Open up PowerShell, navigate to the desired subtree, and run the following command:

```
ls -Force | ?{$_.mode -match "h"}
```